# Override default signature of __getitem__ in autodoc for sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have a class Foo that supports subscripting, so if foo is an instance of Foo, foo[12] will find the 12th one. Foo is defined something like this:

```
class Foo:
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        """Get the ith element of self."""
        ....
```

The sphinx rst file looks something like this:

```
.. autoclass:: Foo
    :members: __getitem__, ...
```

When sphinx builds the documentation, Foo's subscript-implementing `__getitem__` member function is documented as:

> **__getitem__**(i)
>
> Get the ith element of the Foo.

But that function signature will be confusing to a reader of the documentation who does not know about Python dunder functions, and who does not know that subscripting brackets are defined with `__getitem__`. It would be better to have `__getitem__` documented like this:

> **foo[i]**
>
> Get the ith element of the Foo foo.

Is there a way to override the member function signature with `foo[i]`, which does not look like a signature at all?

Comment: I'm not sure you're doing this right. Have you tried adding `__getitem__` with `:special-members:` as described [here](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html)?

Comment: The behavior of `:special-members:` is curious. When `:members:` is used without a explicit list of members, `:special-members:` is needed to specify dunders. But when `:members:` has an explicit list (e.g. `:members: foo, bar`), `:special-members:` has no effect at all. It seems that an explicit list of members requires any dunders to be included in the list. (In my case that is not unreasonable, as I have only a few members that I want documented, and only two dunders.)

And in any case, `:special-members:` seems only about whether a dunder is documented, not how the signature looks.

Comment: The buggy behaviour of `special-members` was fixed in Sphinx 1.8. See https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2401.

Comment: Related proposal: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/5702